# Google Sign In not returning User Info - Errors in documentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm using the Google Sign In documentation from here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide

In 2. Changes for the ViewController implementation file, I'm getting an error in Xcode for retrieving the user info:

```
GIDSignIn* signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
   // Xcode error:  Property 'fetchEmailToggle' not found on object type 'LoginViewController', did you mean to access instance variable 'fetchEmailToggle'?
   if (self.fetchEmailToggle.isEnabled) {
      signIn.shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES;
}
[signIn setClientID: kClientId];
[signIn setScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"]];
[signIn setDelegate: self];
//  Xcode error:  Property 'statusField' not found on object type 'LoginViewController'
self.statusField.text = @"Initialized auth2...";
```

The login is working, but not returning user info.

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the complete error messages from XCode into your question?

Comment: See my answer. Are you migrating an existing project to Google Sign-in, or are you adding Google Sign-in to a new project?

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue. The code in the migration guide is from a sample, and it's referencing some elements from that sample.  Try the following instead:

```
GIDSignIn* signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES;
[signIn setClientID: kClientId];
[signIn setScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"]];
[signIn setDelegate: self];
NSLog(@"Initialized auth2...");
```

By the way: if you want to allow sign-in for all Google users, not just Google+ ones, then delete the `[signIn setScopes:…]` line.

Comment: Yes, I tried unwrapping the if statement, but the user info from Google still doesn't show up.

Comment: You should be able to get that information in the `signIn:didSignInForUser:withError` delegate method.  Put a breakpoint in your implementation, and make sure it's being called (then, inspect the `GIDGoogleUser` object, it should contain the profile information).  Docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/people

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Should that `signIn:didSignInForUser:withError` be in the AppDelegate or the ViewController?

Comment: That method should in the object that you assigned as the delegate to GIDSignIn with `[signIn setDelegate: self];`.  It's up to you which object in your project you'd like to use as the delegate. Generally the ViewController that houses the Sign-in button is a good candidate.

Comment: Ok, I thought I should put it in the ViewController with the button.

Comment: You thought correctly :) generally that makes the most sense.